# SQL tables names within column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to identify the useful fields to include in a query with many joins from many tables.

`select top 10 *
< many
joins >`

field output:
`A | B | C | D | .... | B | .... | B`

the `Bs` come from different tables which are the same field. Is there a way to have a field name in the form of `table_name.column_name`, i.e. `Table23.B` etc?

I note there are many questions showing all the columns in a table, but I'd like to have the table in the column name - is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: We need a more clear speciification of the problem you are too vague and generic. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: No! You must read the tables definition AND infer what to do with this mess. A easier way I do it is by naming meaningfull aliases to the tables and adding all usefull columns table-by-table with the help of the aliases and intellisense

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: YES . You can do that but not with a period '.' between them , you can achieve this with '_' for example.

```
SELECT Table1.B as Table1_B,
       Table1.A,
       Table2.B as Table2_B
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON(Table1.CommonCol = Table2.CommonCol)
```